# How do you find out how much time a system spends waiting for IO?

Tags: linux, performance

Is there a linux command that allows you to see a processes IO wait time vs. CPU time?  I'm trying to see whether some processes are IO-bound or CPU-bound.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think **[iostat](http://gd.tuwien.ac.at/linuxcommand.org/man_pages/iostat1.html)** is the basic tool you want.

Comment: Handy tip...  "iostat 30" will give you overall stats on startup, then update every 30 seconds with activity from the last 30 seconds.  The initial display will give you a snapshot of overall IO usage, and the regular update will indicate whether the system is IO bound now.

Answer (score 6):

Have a look at [iotop](http://guichaz.free.fr/iotop/).

Answer (score 0):

If you install the [atsar](http://packages.debian.org/stable/admin/atsar) package you can look at the system's CPU and I/O stats.  Simply using top should give let you know if the a particular process is CPU or memory bound.  I am not sure how you see the I/O stats for a particular process.

Answer (score 0):

[top (1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/top) will show this information.  You can specify a particular process ID with `-p`.

Answer (score 0):

Try [mpstat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mpstat) and look at %iowait.

```
[pdurbin@beamish ~]$ mpstat 1 5
Linux 2.6.18-128.1.10.el5 (beamish)    05/14/2009

03:25:27 PM  CPU   %user   %nice    %sys %iowait    %irq   %soft  %steal   %idle    intr/s
03:25:28 PM  all    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00  100.00   1073.00
03:25:29 PM  all    0.25    0.00    0.50    0.00    0.00    0.25    0.00   99.00   1202.00
03:25:30 PM  all    1.50    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   98.50   1071.00
03:25:31 PM  all    0.25    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   99.75   1150.00
03:25:32 PM  all    0.25    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   99.75   1086.00
Average:     all    0.45    0.00    0.10    0.00    0.00    0.05    0.00   99.40   1116.40
```